# JLabel: setPreferredSize manually but getPreferredSize after setText

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, settext

i want to set the size of a `JLabel` to a specific (minimum) size via `setPreferredSize()`.
If the text inside the `JLabel` doesn't fit anymore, the `JLabel` should grow.

The problem now is:

- after `label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));`
- i do `setText("new long text");` but the size won't change

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class LabelTest
{
    public static void createWindow()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Text");
        System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 25
        label.setText("New long text");
        System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 77 - JLabel grows as expected

        label.setText("Text");
        System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 25
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
        System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 50 - JLabel grows to given size as expected
        label.setText("New long text");
        System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 50 - it should be 77 again

        frame.add(label);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createWindow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So i need a solution to get the new preferred size when a text is set after i already set the preferred size manually.

If you need more information just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So in fact, you would like something like the possibility to override getMinimumSize()... Hmmm.

Comment: unrelated: [don't use setXXSize, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657)

Comment: Once you invoke setPreferredSize() the size of the label will never change dynamically again. You need to use setPreferredSize(null). The better option is so use a layout manager that will respect the min/preferred sizes, like a BoxLayout or GrigBagLayout.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @camickr ! setPrefferedSize(null) is exactly what i needed in my case, although I knwo that a LayoutManager would be better!

Answer (score 2):

You can reach what you want using a LayoutManager
Below is a example with GridBag Layout

```
public class GridBagExample extends JFrame {

    private JPanel      contentPane;
    private JLabel      lblMyLabel;
    private JTextField  textField;
    private JButton     btnChangeMyLabel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GridBagExample frame = new GridBagExample();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GridBagExample() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 94);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 344, 0 };
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        lblMyLabel = new JLabel(" My Label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblMyLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblMyLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblMyLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_lblMyLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblMyLabel.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(lblMyLabel, gbc_lblMyLabel);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        btnChangeMyLabel = new JButton("Change My Label");
        btnChangeMyLabel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                lblMyLabel.setText("This is the new text of my JLabel");
            }
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnChangeMyLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnChangeMyLabel.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_btnChangeMyLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_btnChangeMyLabel.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(btnChangeMyLabel, gbc_btnChangeMyLabel);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To set a minimum size, use `setMinimumSize(Dimension)`. In most cases, it is better to place the `JLabel` in a container with a suitable layout manager, and to set size on it.

---

Return value of `getPreferredSize()` is automatically calculated until you set an explicit preferred size. After this, `getPreferredSize()` will be return with this specific size. If you reset preferred size (by setting it to `null`), then automatic size will be again available. In your case:

```
label.setText("Text");
System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 25
label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 50
label.setText("New long text");
System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 50
label.setPreferredSize(null);
System.out.println(label.getPreferredSize().width); // 77
```